# Laravel observer in pivot table not triggering

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, observers

I created a observer for my pivot table `CreatorListing` and I dont know why it wont trigger the `created` event. I even tried others like `creating, saving, and saved` but they wont go through.

Here is in my controller

```
    public function getSponsored(Listing $listing)
    {
        $this->authorize('canRequestGetSponsored', $listing);
        $listing->creators()->attach(auth()->user()->creator->id, [
            'workflow' => new ValueObjectsWorkflow(PlatformType::Google)
        ]);

        return response()->ok(null, __('Listing added. Accept the contract to continue.'));
    }
```

In my listing model

```
   public function creators()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Creator::class)
            ->withPivot('counter_offer', 'workflow', 'is_contract_signed', 'is_accepted', 'review_status')
            ->withTimestamps()->using(CreatorListing::class);
    }
```

In my observer, its just a simple `dd` statement

```
    public function created(CreatorListing $creatorListing)
    {
        dd(1);
    }
```

Before, I when diddnt add the `->using(CreatorListing::class);` line. The code shows no errors but it wont call the `dd` or the observer event. Now that I added that line it says `Array to string conversion`. I dont know what I am missing or did I do something wrong?

I just follow this article for the reference https://mayahi.net/laravel/observe-pivot-tables-in-laravel/

Comment: Register the observer in a service provider Model::observe(Observer::class);

Answer (score 1):

```
public function boot()
{
    Pivot::observe(PivotObserver::class);
}
```

Add this in a service provider.
Also the Pivot should extend Model. Define the relations explicit and do not let laravel guess the columns.

Comment: i already added the observer in the provider. still no luck.

Comment: The pivot should extend Model. For me it works.